# Rosmake error with package csm

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to install the scan_tools library with rosmake. However I have an error when it build the csm package (if I rosmake the other package it works)

Here the error I get:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['csm']                                                                                                                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/cyprien/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120914-112111                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['csm'] to:
['csm']                                                                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> csm [ make ]                                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] All 32 linessm: 0.9 sec ]                                                                                                             [ 1 Active 0/1 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p build
  if [ ! -f csm-git-23703a998fff57250322.tar.gz.md5sum ]; then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum file csm-git-23703a998fff57250322.tar.gz.md5sum" && false; fi
  `rospack find rosbuild`/bin/download_checkmd5.py https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/csm-git-23703a998fff57250322.tar.gz build/csm-git-23703a998fff57250322.tar.gz `awk {'print $1'} csm-git-23703a998fff57250322.tar.gz.md5sum`
  [rosbuild] Downloading https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/csm-git-23703a998fff57250322.tar.gz to build/csm-git-23703a998fff57250322.tar.gz...Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 58, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 30, in main
      urllib.urlretrieve(uri, dest)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 93, in urlretrieve
      return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 239, in retrieve
      fp = self.open(url, data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 207, in open
      return getattr(self, name)(url)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 436, in open_https
      h.endheaders(data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
      self._send_output(message_body)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
      self.send(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
      self.connect()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1161, in connect
      self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 381, in wrap_socket
      ciphers=ciphers)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
      self.do_handshake()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
      self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package csm written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/cyprien/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120914-112111/csm/build_output.log                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< csm [FAIL] [ 0.89 seconds ]                                                                                                                       
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package csm. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                       
[ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                              
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] /home/cyprien/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120914-112111
```

I tried to go into download_checkmd5.py to see what's going on, and it seems to be a problem of mismatch md5sum, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your help

Cyprien Descheemaeker

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43834/rosmake-error-with-package-csm/) by [Cyprien](https://answers.ros.org/users/3199/cyprien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved :
I just downloaded the tar file in scan_tools/csm/build, and relaunch the rosmake

---

Originally posted by [Cyprien](https://answers.ros.org/users/3199/cyprien/) with karma: 18 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0